# Why is my box not appearing in my section?

Tags: html, css

I am not understanding why the box i have created is not appearing in my section. I have a slideshow above but i don't think its affecting it. I have checked that it dimensions should fit in the section but it is appearing just below. [What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v8zb.png)

Here is my HTML:

```css
#main {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #7EFFF7;
}

.gojima {}

.article1 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77ebcf 20%, #ffffff 20%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  position: relative;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 295px;
  width: 650px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.article1 h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}

.article1 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#main2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="gojima">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="hp1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article1">
    <h1> THE RICE BURGER TREND</h1>
    <p>Guess what? Burger nerds stuck in an unending "brioche vs milk bun" argument now have a new topic to battle: the bun-free burger. They can test out the merits of this trend at Gojima, Sydney's first rice burger bar, which opened at The Star.</p>
  </div>

</section>


<section id="main2">
  <div class="mbassy">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="hp2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article2">
    <h2> THE LOCAL EMBASSY BOILER-ROOM</h2>
    <p> On a bright corner of Wattle Street in Ultimo is a busy cafe, The Local Mbassy. Soft music from the ‘20s plays and locals enjoy the view across Wentworth Park, tucking into burgers, pancakes and pans of baked eggs and sipping on Campos coffee.</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float .`gojima` left to allow the other content to sit next to it. You also probably don't need `float:right` on `.article1`.

```css
#main {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #7EFFF7;
}

.gojima {
  float: left;
}

.article1 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77ebcf 20%, #ffffff 20%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  position: relative;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 295px;
  width: 650px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.article1 h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}

.article1 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#main2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="gojima">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="hp1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article1">
    <h1> THE RICE BURGER TREND</h1>
    <p>Guess what? Burger nerds stuck in an unending "brioche vs milk bun" argument now have a new topic to battle: the bun-free burger. They can test out the merits of this trend at Gojima, Sydney's first rice burger bar, which opened at The Star.</p>
  </div>

</section>


<section id="main2">
  <div class="mbassy">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="hp2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article2">
    <h2> THE LOCAL EMBASSY BOILER-ROOM</h2>
    <p> On a bright corner of Wattle Street in Ultimo is a busy cafe, The Local Mbassy. Soft music from the ‘20s plays and locals enjoy the view across Wentworth Park, tucking into burgers, pancakes and pans of baked eggs and sipping on Campos coffee.</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the box you have created is not appearing inside of your section is because the div "gojima" is implicitly set to "display: block", despite the fact that you haven't changed the styles for this div.

To fix your problem, simply make this edit to your css file:

```
.gojima {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To place the picture and text blocks side by side, you should add either `float: left;` OR `display: inline-block` to the first child of each `section` ( `.gojima, .mbassy`), and apply the same CSS to the second child of the second section as for the second child of the first section ( `.article1, .article2`):

```css
#main {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #7EFFF7;
}

.gojima, .mbassy {
float: left;
}

.article1, .article2 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #77ebcf 20%, #ffffff 20%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  position: relative;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 295px;
  width: 650px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.article1 h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}

.article1 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#main2 {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="gojima">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="hp1" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article1">
    <h1> THE RICE BURGER TREND</h1>
    <p>Guess what? Burger nerds stuck in an unending "brioche vs milk bun" argument now have a new topic to battle: the bun-free burger. They can test out the merits of this trend at Gojima, Sydney's first rice burger bar, which opened at The Star.</p>
  </div>

</section>


<section id="main2">
  <div class="mbassy">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="hp2" width="300" height="300" /></a>
  </div>

  <div class="article2">
    <h2> THE LOCAL EMBASSY BOILER-ROOM</h2>
    <p> On a bright corner of Wattle Street in Ultimo is a busy cafe, The Local Mbassy. Soft music from the ‘20s plays and locals enjoy the view across Wentworth Park, tucking into burgers, pancakes and pans of baked eggs and sipping on Campos coffee.</p>
  </div>

</section>
```